# Quill-emoji: Quill editor emoji remove issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I am using Quill-editor,
when I add emoji in quill editor this code enter in the editor you can see the following screen sort
[image]

But when I remove the emoji from the quill editor that time emoji is remove but emoji code is not remove from the quill

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue. I downloaded the [Quill Emoji repo](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji), a Quill module extension that you appear to be using, and ran the [demo page](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji/tree/master/demo) locally.

The code generated by our two versions does not look similar at all. What version of Quill Emoji are you using?

You should try upgrading your Quill and Quill Emoji versions to the latest. The demo I tested with uses Quill 1.3.5 and the latest `master` version of Quill Emoji.

### Before deleting emoji:

[image: Quill editor panel and dev tools after adding emoji]

### After deleting emoji:

[image: Quill editor panel and dev tools after deleting added emoji]

Comment: My current Quill Emoji version is 0.1.7

Comment: and My current Quill version is 1.3.3

Comment: I updated both Quill Emoji Quill version but this issue is coun't fix !

Comment: Does the demo work for you? You'll have to share your code and give us details about your browser

Comment: currently not, I am working with old quill and emoji version.

Comment: I am unable to find any solution about this.

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya have you tried the [demo](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji/tree/master/demo) linked above?

Comment: I can create an online test when I get a moment, but if you want to try before then all you need is the `index.html` and `../dist/quill-emoji.js` from that repository